# Como validar checkbox en una tabla

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table class="table" id="tableImport">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" id="checkBoxAll"/></th>
                                <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerID}]]</th>
                                <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customer}]]</th>
                                <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerEmail}]]</th>
                                <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerPhone}]]</th>
                                <th scope="col">[[#{table.importExcel.customerTotal}]]</th>
                                <th scope="col">Debt Age (Days)</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="debtFileTO:${debtFileTOs}">
                                <td>
                                    <input id="selecteds" type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" th:value="${debtFileTO.customerid}" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
                                </td>
                                <td th:text="${debtFileTO.customerid}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${debtFileTO.customernombre}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${debtFileTO.customeremail}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${debtFileTO.customerphone}"></td>
                                <td th:text="'$'+${#numbers.formatInteger(debtFileTO.totaldebt,3,'POINT')}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${debtFileTO.debtage}"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Necesito validar que si ninguna fila se encuentra con el checkbox activo, me muestre un mensaje en un span que diga "seleccione al menos 1 cliente".

De momento lo estoy haciendo así con javaScript pero soy bastante nuevo en el tema y no me funciona.

Script:

```
<script>
        function validateCustomers(){
            var customersSelecteds;
            customersSelecteds =document.getElementById('selecteds').value;
            if (customersSelecteds ==="") {
                document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "Seleccione al menos un cliente";
                return false
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Este es mi span y boton con el que valido e intento mostrar el mensaje:

```
<span id="demo"></span>
                    <input style="position: static" type="submit" onclick="validateCustomers()" class="btn btn-primary" value="Configure Campaign"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tiene sentido usar IDs porque están repetidos y [deben ser únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), además, `document.getElementById()` te va a devolver solo el primer elemento que encuentre con el ID especificado.

En HTML solo elimina esos ID repetidos. Desde Javascript accedes a los checkboxes con [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), que te va a devolver todos los elementos que cumplan con el selector:

- Selector por clase: `.chkCheckBoxId` Solo se agrega el punto al inicio del nombre de clase
- Agregar al selector para obtener solo los marcados: `:checked`

Vas a obtener una [lista de nodos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList) que puedes consultar cantidad de elementos (length) o recorrer (forEach).

```js
// Ejecutar cuando se haga clic en el botón
document.querySelector('#comprueba').addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Obtener checkbox por clase y solo los marcados
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.chkCheckBoxId:checked');
    if(inputs.length == 0) {
        console.log('Debes seleccionar al menos un cliente');
        // Salir de la función
        return;
    }
    // Aquí haces lo que debas hacer con cada checkbox
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        console.log(input.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" value="1" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" value="2" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" value="3" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" value="4" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="customersSelecteds" value="5" class="chkCheckBoxId"/>

<p>
    <button type="button" id="comprueba">Comprobar</button>
</p>
```